# Is there a platform/service agnostic definition for service handoff?

Tags: rest, service, cloud, paas

I'm curious if there is a spec for a service handoff definition.  For example, if on a PaaS/IaaS a service is provisioned, end users need a hash of details of what the service is, where the endpoint can be reached, what port(s) are published, and what authentication is used.  (Think HATEOAS ref_'s)  I have a couple mock-ups of what one could look like:

**object storage example**

```
name: myobjstor
family: s3
about: https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3
zone: public
protocol:
  spec: http
  host: s3.mysite.com
  port: 443
  tls: true
authentication:
  strategy: oauth2
  username: someuser
  password: somepassword
definition:
  type: swagger
  url: 'https://mysite/swagger.json'
```

**openstack example**

```
name: myostack
family: openstack-keystone_v2.1
about: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref.html
zone: public
protocol:
  spec: http
  host: keystone.mysite.com
  port: 443
  tls: true
authentication:
  strategy: oauth2
  username: someuser
  password: somepassword
definition:
  type: swagger
  url: 'https://mysite/swagger.json'
```

**redis example**

```
name: myredis
family: redis
about: http://redis.io/documentation
zone: public
protocol:
  spec: redis
  host: redis.mysite.com
  port: 6379
options:
  db: 0
```

**nfs example**

```
name: mynfs
family: nfs
about: http://nfs.sourceforge.net
zone: public
protocol:
  spec: nfsv4
  host: nfs.mysite.com
  ports: 
    - 111
    - 2049
```

Is there a standard like this that already exists?

Comment: Who would "consume" this spec? I can think of a case where a client would want access to both an HTTP service and a service with a custom protocol. Why not just give them a REST service for everything? That's the trend I'm seeing.

Comment: This would be a faculty in of the rest call for turning up a service.  For example, if a customer makes a call to turn up a postgres services, the response would include the information of where the endpoint would be consumed (ip, port, protocol, auth, etc).  What I'm curious is if there is already a spec/schema for this kind of response.

Comment: We're in the processes of an rfc around a spec titled "General puprose service activation handoff definition"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you looking into the "service discovery"[pattern](http://microservices.io/patterns/client-side-discovery.html).

There are several tools out there that make it easy to implement, but most of them describe services using key/value pairs e.g. see [etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/0.4.7/etcd-api/) but it looks like Consul adds a few fields that may be of use to you see [here](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/services.html)

Example Consul Definition

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "redis",
    "tags": ["master"],
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 8000,
    "enableTagOverride": false,
    "checks": [
      {
        "script": "/usr/local/bin/check_redis.py",
        "interval": "10s"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```